# Two APC Symmetra LX 16kVA into one common output?

Tags: electrical-power, ups, apc

We have 2x APC symmetra LX 16kVA units running at the moment and have read (in Eaton's documentation) that their UPSs can have a common synchronised output (based on input phase or set phase with a master/slave clock type arrangement) - http://pqlit.eaton.com/ll_download_bylitcode.asp?doc_id=10925

We would like to connect our two UPS units together as at the moment one is a "cold" manual switch standby unit.

Do APC offer a synchronised phase output for N+1 redundancy between chassis and if so are there any special units required to join the outputs or can a standard tie-cabinet be used?

APC's docs aren't so clear on connecting modular (symmetra) UPSes to a common output.
http://www.apcmedia.com/salestools/LARD-8YPBGX/LARD-8YPBGX_R0_EN.pdf

Comment: This is really an APC support issue, given the scale/class/cost of these units.

Comment: Actually it is a "read the marketing and technical baseline material". Like the one the OP even linked to that is VERY clear on the different scenario. I could add, snippily, for someone who knows how to read such diagrams - and anyone else should not make such a decision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

I.e. unless noted otherwise, you must assume that the output inverters of your UPS do not support this configuration.

As it's already been said; best go talk to APC to get all the answers you need.

Answer (score 1):

Check diagram 2.7 in the link you provided.

Comment: +1 That works, too :)

Comment: Fig 2.7 simply shows a Single UPS, under the "Possible Upgrades" section - "on site by connecting several identical UPS units in parallel" - without any mention of any modules etc that may be needed. I think you are referring to Fig 2.8 - this is applicable to MGE units only, Fig 2.11 shows a solution that applies to our units. However searching for Symmetra Static Switch Cublice gives no relevant results.

Comment: Then - cough - talk to your sales representative. Get an offer for the configuration you want. Let people at APC make the work they get paid for.